# First Click on ASP.NET control does not fire on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm seeing this behavior on two of my pages, but I'm just going to ask about the one that's more important to me at the moment. I have a page that loads information from a database into a ASP gridview and then allows the user to add a detail to each populated line.

The issue I'm having is that when the 'Edit' button of the gridview and then subsequently the 'Update' or 'Cancel' button, it takes two click to actually fire the onclick event. A post back does take place on the first click, but nothing actually happens.

I'm including the code that seems relevant below. The page uses a master page and there are a number of divs involved with formatting, I'm excluding those.

Gridview and related controls:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="Plant Selector:  " runat="server" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPlant" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" runat="server" />
        <p />
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" Text="" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblerror" Text="" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowEditing="gridview1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridview1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gridview1_RowUpdating">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="JobNum" HeaderText="Job Number" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ModelNum" HeaderText="Model" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SchCompDate" HeaderText="Sch Comp Date" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt" Width="98%" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text="Click Edit to add details of exception." runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
            </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gridview1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Sample image below:

[image: Sample gridview display]

Here is the code behind:

```
private string Plant { get; set; }

// This sets the default plant based off IP.
protected void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    getPlantFromIP();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        populateDDL();
        BindData();
    }
    else
    {
        Plant = ddlPlant.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}

// Populates the drop down.
private void populateDDL()
{        
    ddlPlant.Items.Add("NC");
    ddlPlant.Items.Add("WA");

    setPlantInDDL();
}

private void setPlantInDDL()
{
    if(Plant == "WA")
    {
        ddlPlant.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
    if (Plant == "NC")
    {
        ddlPlant.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

private void getPlantFromIP()
{
    if (Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "70.103.118.100")
    {
        Plant = "WA";
        //ddlPlant.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Plant = "NC";
        //ddlPlant.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

// Database Query.
private DataTable getDataFromDatabase()
{
    DataTable rTable = new DataTable();

    string plant = ddlPlant.SelectedValue.ToString();

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["workorderConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM reportdatatables.compliance_exception_report
                                    WHERE ExceptionNoted = '0' AND Plant = @plant";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plant", plant);

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                rTable.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return rTable;
}

// Binds the data from the database to the gridview.
private void BindData()
{        
    DataTable data = getDataFromDatabase().Copy();

    gridview1.DataSource = data;
    gridview1.DataBind();
}


protected void ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Plant = ddlPlant.SelectedValue.ToString();
    BindData();
}

// On edit call.
protected void gridview1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

}

// On cancel call.
protected void gridview1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
}

protected void gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}
```

**Here's what I've tried:**

-A lot of posts a read saw this behavior relating to autopostback settings of controls. As you can see I'm made sure to not have any control with the autopostback set to true.

-I had some concern that the behavior might be related to the updatepanel, but removing it doesn't change the behavior at all.

-I read that having AutoEventWireup="true" in your page tag can cause this. I DO have that in my page tag, but setting it to false does not fix the issue and prevents my dropdown from being populated on page load.

-There was another post that suggested the ID of the control could be changing between page load and post back. I monitored the IDs of those controls and I do not see any change in their ID.

So all that being said, I'm hoping someone has a clue as to what I'm missing. If there is any more information I can provide that might help, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When it posts back on first click what events are firing other than page_load can put break point to all other events and see ?

Comment: The only event I see that is firing is the gridview1_RowEditing event.

Comment: So you click on edit button and it goes to RowEditing and the grid isn't changing to edit mode, during the first click right ?

Comment: Correct, only the second. This behavior is repeated with the cancel button once it does go into edit mode (on second click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which will make the grid editable

```
protected void gridview1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
   BindData();
}
```

for cancel also

```
protected void gridview1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
```

Comment: This does fix the issue. I still don't understand why it was happening, though.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Problem is you are not setting the grid in edit mode when you click on edit, which is why it's not working. But some how on the second click it's going to edit mode. Which I don't know :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the part that has me confused. You would expect it to not work at all.